# Input submit button value disappears when clicked in IE9

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, input, internet-explorer-9

I'm running into a weird issue with submit buttons in IE9.  When the "Continue" or "Back" input is clicked, the value disappears.

Comment: works Ok for me mostly - sometimes I can see something like 'Demo Organisation' between clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** The issue ended up being a js conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be putting an onclick event on a submit input. A better way to do it would be put an onsubmit on the form and put a javascript function in it which dictates the action of the form depending on the value of the submit button value